# Selenium Chrome either can't find start location or freezes, Firefox works fine

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have Selenium installed, and I have Chrome installed.  I am using python bindings, on linux.  Firefox works fine, but I can't get Chrome to work.

If I don't specify an argument in the chrome driver, I get this:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 68, in start
    and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.                 Please download from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list                and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

Then I read that link.  It says the place selenium expects chrome to be installed is `/usr/bin/google-chrome`

I check, and sure enough...

```
$ which google-chrome 
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

So, try again, with arguments:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome')
```

Great, Chrome starts, so I know webdriver finds it.  However, the assignment does not complete.  It runs and hangs.  Unlike Firefox, running this does not release control to the script.  I have to hit ctrl-C to wrest control away, and am unable to use the driver object.

In firefox, on the other hand...

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.method # etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have u downloaded the [Chrome Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)?

This driver is something that is needed in tandem with the google chrome borwser.

To get set up, first download the appropriate prebuilt server. Make sure the server can be located on your PATH or specify its location via the webdriver.chrome.driver system property.

Comment: Yeah, I've installed it---do you know what the command is for setting the path?  I have it in my home, but still isn't being found.  `webdriver.chrome.options.Options.binary_location ="~/"` failed, among other things...